# Assign different part of codes to st.button in streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit

I am building an streamlit app, I defined 3 buttons.
I have a large set of codes that does different things. If a user choose button1, it does something, if a user choose button2 it should perform other part of code and does something else.

There is two issue I am dealing with:

1- when I select button2, and then I select slider, or change the option in st.sidebar.checkbox, which are defined inside this if, it doesn't do anything.

2- how to define data frame under buttom2 which can be called under button 3 as well?

3- if I define slider and st.sidebar.checkbox outside of the **if button2**, the problem of 1 will be solved but what is outside of **if button2**, will be shown also in **if button1**.

Can you help me to develop this code further?

```py
import streamlit as st

col1, col2, col3 = st.columns([.4,.5,1])

m = st.markdown("""
<style>
div.stButton > button:first-child {
    background-color: rgb(0,250,154);
}
</style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)


with col1:
    button1 = st.button('In')

with col2:
    button2 = st.button('DA')

with col3:
    button3 = st.button('Vi')

if button1:
    write some intro text
if button2:
    a data frame is generated here
    there is slider and st.sidebar.checkbox defined in this part.
if button3:
    use the data frame generated in button2 and plot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `st.tabs` and `st.cache_data` instead:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

tab1, tab2, tab3 = st.tabs(["In", "Da", "Vi"])


@st.cache_data()
def create_dataframe(slider_val):
    # This pretends it's a long computation..
    import time
    time.sleep(5)
    return pd.DataFrame({"aa": [slider_val]})


def show_dataframe(df):
    st.dataframe(df)


with tab1:
    st.header("In")
    st.image("https://static.streamlit.io/examples/cat.jpg", width=200)

with tab2:
    st.header("DA")

    slider_val = st.slider("Foobar", 0, 30, step=10)
    st.write(f"slider_val: {slider_val}")

    df = create_dataframe(slider_val)

with tab3:
    st.header("Vi")
    show_dataframe(df)
```

It gives 3 tabs:

[image] [image] [image]

---

See the `st.tabs` documentation here: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.tabs